# Hibarnate does not write to db sometimes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a threadpool that produces listenableFutures from guava. Upon failure of the task I write in the DB using two methods.

First method writes an entry with various information and second updates that entry with the outcome `Datetime` and value.

```
public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
        //This is the Guava callback function in case of failure
        if (retransmitPolicyFilter.isRetransmittable(thrown, event)) {
            try {
                queue.putLast(event);
                LOGGER.debug("Adding event [{}] last. It failed initially due to [{}]", event, thrown.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error {}", e.getMessage());
                LOGGER.debug("Error {}", e);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                EventLog eventLog = eventLoggingService.logFailedEvent(event, name, thrown);
                if (thrown instanceof ResponseTimeoutException) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error {}", thrown.getMessage());
                    LOGGER.debug("Error {}", thrown);
                    LOGGER.warn("Received a Response Timeout Exception error for event [{}] and I will not retry it", event);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.debug("Error sending event [{}]. Logging event with sid [{}]", event, eventLog.getSid(), thrown);
                    eventLog = eventLoggingService.logOutcomeForEventLog(eventLog.getSid(), "REJECTED");
                    eventService.forwardEventOutcome("REJECTED", eventLog);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error handling failure of event [{}]. {}", event, e.getMessage());
                LOGGER.debug("{}", e);
            }
        }
```

The two methods doing the database inserts and updates are:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public EventLog logFailedEvent(final Event event, final String name, final Throwable thrown) {
    try {
        final EventLog om = prepareEventLog(event, name, null);
        int code = -1;
        if (thrown instanceof TimeoutResponseException) {
            code = ((NegativeResponseException) thrown).getCommandStatus();
        }

        om.setStatus(MessageDeliveryStatusEnum.FAILED.getProperty() + " " + code);

        return eventLogRepository.save(om);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error saving failed event [{}] for name [{}]. {}", event.toString(), name, e.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("{}", e);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public EventLog logOutcomeForEventLog(final long eventId, final String outcomeValue) {
    try {
        final EventLog o = eventLogRepository.findOne(eventId);
        o.setOutcomeReceiveDate(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
        o.setOutcomeValue(outcomeValue);
        return eventLogRepository.save(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error saving outcome for id [{}] and value [{}]. {}", eventId, outcomeValue,
                e.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("{}", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Most events fail so this code is executed thousands of times per minute and there are millions of entries in the DB.

99.9% of the times the above code produces a database entry that has the `outcome_receive_date` and the `outcome_value`

**except**

some times when only the the `eventLoggingService.logFailedEvent(event,name, thrown)` method seems to be executing

**whereas**

the `eventLoggingService.logOutcomeForEventLog(eventLog.getSid(), "REJECTED");` is not updating the entry with the last two values (outcome notification datetime and value). *No error is logged although as you can see from above I am catering for that.*

I am really at a loss here.

Comment: An exception will trigger a rollback, so when an exception occurs it will fail. You will need to start a new transaction to make sure to update the status. You don't want that to participate in the same tx as your business logic.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? The problem is that I have a record written from the first method but for the second method I do not have an update written to that record although I do not see an exception thrown/caught in my logs.

Comment: As stated in case of an exception (`RuntimeException` by default) the whole transaction will be rolled back. So any change done will be rolled back, ie. no trace in the database! You will need to start a new transaction (a fresh non corrupted one) to persist it in the database.

Comment: Agreed. In hat case shouldn't there be an exception in the logs (i.e. `LOGGER.error("Error saving outcome for id...`)? And also you mean the exception is thrown in the `eventLoggingService.logOutcomeForEventLog(eventLog.getSid(), "REJECTED");` method?

Comment: No anywhere that eventually the `onFailure` method is called. I would assume that is from transactional code. However it might be even worse, the exception occurs after the commit which might even be outside the scope of your `onFailure` method.

Comment: the `onFailure` is not called from transactional code. Still if the exception happens outside the `logOutcomeForEventLog` method why isn't the `logFailedEvent` method affected but writes in the database?

Comment: Because an exception occurred and the default behavior is to rollback.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If an exception happens somewhere shouldn't be caught by the try/catch and be logged? Especially since as you say the rollback should have taken place upon exception and the initial record is written in the db then the exception happens after the `logFailedEvent` and probably in the `logOutcomeForEventLog`. But all the code in that method is surrounded by a try/catch. So I should have seen it somewhere in the logs. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your catch inside the transactional method is pretty much useless. The commit happens AFTER returning from the method. So outside the scope of the try / catch.

Comment: That was something I did not know. Thank you. What about the catch in the `onFailure` is that equally useless?